# How to echo json object from url as a string

Tags: php, json

I using this to get json from url:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/testuser/?__a=1');
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);

var_dump($parsed_json);
```

and I get json response back as:

```
    {"user": 
 {"username": "testuser", "has_blocked_viewer": false, "follows":
 {"count": 94}, "requested_by_viewer": false, "followed_by":
 {"count": 3}, "country_block": null, "has_requested_viewer": false,
               "external_url_linkshimmed": null, "follows_viewer": false,
               "profile_pic_url_hd": "https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg",
               "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg",
               "is_private": true, "full_name": null, "media":
 {"count": 0, "page_info":
 {"has_previous_page": false, "start_cursor": null, 
  "end_cursor": null, "has_next_page": false},
  "nodes": []},
  "blocked_by_viewer": false,
  "followed_by_viewer": false, "is_verified": false,
  "id": "3409891", "biography": null, "external_url": null}
}
```

how can I echo the "profile_pic_url_hd" as a string ?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct? If you echo $json_string, do you get anything?

Comment: You can't really print an array. var_dump($parsed_json) and see what you get.

Comment: if you know you are getting error ssl (no certificate installed yet) because download https, please change this question or you can delete this

Comment: I just edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Using `json_decode` with `true` as second parameter, you get an associative array and you can't `print` or `echo` arrays.
Try `var_dump` or `print_r`:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1');
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
print_r($parsed_json);
var_dump($parsed_json);
```

Also make sure, that the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check for error/exceptions. In the following I assumed that 'user' and 'profile_pic_url' exist in the returned json response (The returned json response is a hash of hashes).

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/testuser/?__a=1');
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
print_r($parsed_json{'user'}{'profile_pic_url'});
?>
```

*Response:*

```
https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg
```